# Why is my element not clicking in selenium after defining xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a selenium code to go to a website and click on the following element to expand its drop down list:

[image: Reports]

Now this area is comprised of two elements.

**Element 1:**

[image]

Element code: `<b class="icon" id="handler2"></b>`

Full Xpath: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li/ul/li/p/b`

**Element 2:**

[image]

Element code: `<p class="wrap button draggable" id="anonymous_element_1"><b class="icon" id="handler2"></b>Reports</p>`

Full Xpath: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li/ul/li/p`

I used element 1. My selenium code is lengthy but the the line i used to click 'reports' is:

```
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li/ul/li/p/b').click()
```

It doesn't click the button though. I'm not sure why. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?. **It is worth noting that if you use element 2, then a double click is required.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="handler2"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks. The code works but it turns out that this code only works once the element has loaded (in my case), as it takes a second or so to load. But if I type: import time time.sleep(1) then it works. Without it it doesn't. How can I rewrite the code to say execute it once the item has loaded rather than using time.sleep().? e.g. WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("Search")

Comment: @HamidBee No, You  must have to give  load time as you said meaing  using time.sleep or webdriverwait. Thanks